# Can't load Java projects in Netbeans 8 after downgrading my mac from Java 8 to Java 7

Tags: java, netbeans

I had Netbeans working fine with Java 8.  Today i removed Java 8 from the system (a Max OS X system) and installed Java 7.  Now when netbeans loads it loads without java projects and won't let me create new java projects (i can create HTML projects etc).  I looked at the Java Platform settings in Netbeans and it seems to have the correct SDK version (1.7) indicated there.  Do you know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: why did you downgrade?

Comment: If you didn't have any specific settings changed, I would suggest to simply remove the `.netbeans` folder from your home directory (or maybe `~/etc/netbeans.conf` too - I don't know the OS X specific path). That should sometimes help, if there is any setting for JDK 8 left in the configuration. But this solution shouldn't be the ultimate answer. Edit: Maybe you better first have a look at the [configuration file](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf) and search for any old JDK 8 related entry! That should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed Netbeans 8 and the problem is resolved.